# How do you add a group of values and output the entire group at once?

Tags: vba, excel, collections

In VBA how do you add a group of values and output the entire group at once?

Essentially I'm looking to do something like:

```
Todays_Date = 9/1/15 
If Compliance_Date1 = Todays_Date  then
    Collection.add “Compliance Date 1”
If Compliance_Date2 = Todays_Date  then
   Collection.add “Compliance Date 2”
If Compliance_Date3 = Todays_Date  then
   Collection.add “Compliance Date 3”

 Output Entire Collection: Compliance Date 1 Compliance Date 2 Compliance Date 3
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "output them"?

Comment: @MatthewD - I just assume how do you get them out of the macro, and display/use them somewhere.  You can use `Debug.print`, or `Range("A1") = Compliance_Date1 &", "&compliance_date2&", "&compliance_date3`.  (only, I'm new to collections, so I don't know if that is literally how to output them, my point is you can use things such as debug.print, set a range equal, etc.)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. and yes exactly though my challenge is that sometimes it's just one date, others two or three. I just want it output whatever is in the collection. I'll try the debug.print and let you know if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know how to use collections you may want to stay with a string.

```
Dim strDateList as string

If Compliance_Date1 = Todays_Date  then
    strDateList = strDateList & “Compliance Date 1” & vbCrLf
If Compliance_Date2 = Todays_Date  then
   strDateList = strDateList & “Compliance Date 2” & vbCrLf
If Compliance_Date3 = Todays_Date  then
   strDateList = strDateList & “Compliance Date 3” & vbCrLf
```

Then "output them"

```
msgbox strDateList
```